# how to start browser on Windows Phone Emulator from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm trying to automate the testing of a web page on a Windows Phone Emulator.

For that I need to launch the browser from a command line, but I haven't found anything to do this.

Can you help me?

Comment: +1. For opening emulator i know is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XDE Launcher\XdeLauncher.exe" "Windows Phone 7" "Windows Phone Emulator - 512 MB"` but i wanted to know what else i needed to open emulator already opening IE Browser at the URL i want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. You make a simple app with a WebBrowser control. Now, you can start this app from command prompt,

**This launches an app from PC:**

```
XapDeployCmd.exe /launch <Product ID/Xap FileName> <targetdevice[:param]>
```

You can get `targetdevice[:param]` from `XapDeployCmd.exe /enumerateDevices`. You also know the `Product ID` of your app.

This XapDeployCmd is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment`

Example

```
XapDeployCmd.exe /launch f8ce6878-0aeb-497f-bcf4-65be961d4bba /targetdevice:0
```